# Polar histogram and bins

Tags: list-manipulation, histograms

I have a list of polar coordinate points:

`list = Transpose[Join[RandomReal[{1, 60}, {1, 100}], 
        RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, {1, 100}]]]`

I need to divide the circle into 16 angle sectors (`Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/16]`) and 4 radius sectors (`Range[0, 100, 25]`).  I need to count the number of points that fallen into each two-component sector (there are $16\times4 = 64$ such two-component sectors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BinCounts[list, {0, 100, 25}, {0, 2π, π/8}] //MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 4 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 4 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: this solution is not  complete! It gives jut 16 sectors

Answer (score 1):

```
list = Transpose[{RandomReal[{1, 60}, 100], RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 100]}];

BinCounts[#[[All, 2]], {0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/16}] & /@ Partition[list, 25] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

also:

```
HistogramList[list, {{0, 60, 15}, {0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}}][[2]]
```

reading again, the r bin should be `{0,100,25}`. The last bin will of course be empty since your random data ends at `60`